# ASP .NET C# Change from Military time to Standard Time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(time.Text);
if (DateTime.Parse(time.Text) > DateTime.Parse("12:00:00 AM")
    && DateTime.Parse(time.Text) < DateTime.Parse("11:59:59 AM"))                                    
{
    time.Text = time.Text + " AM";
}
else
{
    time.Text = time.Text + " PM";
}
```

What I have now is 16:34 PM,

I want it to display 04:34 PM

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply

```
string strTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss tt");
```

in your case, it will be:

```
 time.Text=DateTime.Parse(time.Text).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss tt");
```

and make sure about custom formats, like `HH` is 24 hrs format, `MM` is for month

Comment: When you use punctuation in a format string, it's always best to escape it with a backslash: `@"hh\:mm\:ss tt"`. The colon is not a colon, but rather a "time separator". If you change your Windows preferences (for some bizarre reason) so that time has hyphens instead of colons, then run `.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`, your output will be `12-34-56` instead of `12:34:56`. (same is true for the forward-slash in the date part). If you need a specific format, I'd always recommend being as specific as possible.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
time.Text = DateTime.Parse(time.Text).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ToLongTimeString` and the other similar methods use the system time preferences (control panel -> region and language) to display. I always prefer specifically formatting output (`@"HH\:mm"` for example) when you need a specific output.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string FormattedTime(this TimeSpan TimeIn24Hours)
    {
        String TimeIn12Hours = string.Empty;
        if (TimeIn24Hours != null)
        {
            TimeIn12Hours = DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(TimeIn24Hours.Hours).AddMinutes(TimeIn24Hours.Minutes).ToString("hh:mm");
        }
        return TimeIn12Hours;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void UpdateTime()
{
    int hours, mins, sec;
    string TimeofDate = "AM";
    currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    hours = Convert.ToInt32(currentTime.Hour.ToString());
    mins = Convert.ToInt32(currentTime.Minute.ToString());
    sec = Convert.ToInt32(currentTime.Second.ToString());

    // lbCurrentTime.Text = currentTime.ToLongTimeString();
    // label2.Text = hours.ToString() + ":" + mins.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString();

    if (hours >= 12)
    {
        hours = hours - 12;
        TimeofDate = "PM";
    }
    else TimeofDate = "AM";

    lbCurrentTime.Text = hours.ToString() + ":" + mins.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString()+" "+TimeofDate;
}
```